# The range of a argmin function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

I have the following function:
$$f(a)=\text{argmin}_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2}(1-a)(b_i-t)^2+a| b_i-t |\right\}\quad ,a\in[0,1]$$

Define $\bar{\beta}$ to be the mean of n observations $b_i$, and $\hat{\beta}$ the median.

Assume $\bar{\beta}\le \hat{\beta}$, how does one prove that

$$\bar{\beta}\le f(a)\le \hat{\beta} \quad \text{for all} \quad a\in[0,1]$$

with the lower inequality achieved for $a=0$ and upper for $a=1$

Comment: I changed the tilde to a hat, it was very hard to tell the median from the mean before.

Comment: Yeah that is better. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When $a=0$ we have,

$$f(0) =\arg\min\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2}(b_i-t)^2\}$$

Take the derivative of the objective function $h(t)$,

$$h'(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^nt-b_i$$

Find the critical point,

$$h'(t) = 0 \implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i = nt\implies t=\bar{\beta}$$

When $a=1$ we have,

$$f(1) = \arg\min\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|b_i-t|\}$$

Let $\textbf{t}$ be the vector of length $n$, $\textbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\\vdots\\ b_n\end{pmatrix}$, and $C=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:y_i=y_j\forall i,j\}$. Then we have,

$$f(1) = \arg\min\limits_{\textbf{t}\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|\textbf{b}-\textbf{t}\|_1+i_{C}(\textbf{t})\implies 0\in\partial \|\textbf{b}-f(1)\textbf{1}\|_1+N_C(f(1)\textbf{1})$$

The set $N_C(f(1)\textbf{1})$ is the set of vectors whose components sum to $0$. So $0=u+v$ for some $u\in \partial\|\textbf{b}-f(1)\textbf{1}\|_1$ and $v\in N_C(f(1)\textbf{1})$. For the vector $u$ we have,

$$u_i = \begin{cases}\mbox{sign}(f(1)-b_i) & b_i\neq f(1),\\ [-1,1] & b_i=f(1)\end{cases}$$
 and since $0=v+u$ we have that the components of $u$ must sum to $0$ as they do for $-v$. Without loss of generality choose $u_i=\mbox{sign}(f(1)-b_i)$ for all $i$. This gives,

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n u_i =0,\\
\implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mbox{sign}(f(1)-b_i)=0$$

So, $f(1)$ must be the median $\hat{\beta}$ since we could just reorder the $b_i$ according to $\leq$ and find that half the $b_i$ are greater than or equal to $f(1)$ and half the $b_i$ are less than or equal to $f(1)$. This is kind of glossing over whether or not there are repeats in the observations, i.e. $b_i=b_j$ for some $i,j$ would mean we might have choose some $u_i$ to account for that instead.

Comment: so we have the end points, but what about the inequality, the bound on f(a)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm curious how to show the inequality.

Comment: I was given hint that one may conider the right and left derivatives to analyze the monotonicity properties. I have not solved it tho.

Comment: that's too bad, it's an interesting problem!